# How to FIX Apache Cordova vulnerabilities in my mobile app

Tags: android, apache, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a mobile app using Dreamweaver and Phonegap. it all went OK but when I trying to upload my APK to the Google developer console, I got this mail....

"
Hello Google Play Developer,

We rejected [Myappname], with package name [packagename], for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Apache Cordova
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.

You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help Center article.

"

Please someone help me with this.How do I fix it...?
Here is my config.xml file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.myapp"
    versionCode = "11"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

 <name>My App Name</name>
 
 <description>
    description
 </description>

 <author href="https://author.com" email="info@author.com">
 author
 </author>
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
 <preference name="windows-identity-name" value="PhonegapBuild.PGBDeveloper" />
 

 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.3.0" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.2" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.2" />

  <splash src="splash.png" />
  
    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="img/icon.png" />
    <icon src="img/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="img/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="img/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="img/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="img/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="img/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="img/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="img/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="img/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="img/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="img/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="img/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="img/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />




<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />


</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

As its mentioned clearly in the rejection message, you are using very old version of Cordova (4.x)

Try upgrading your app to latest version of Cordova (6.x) You may have to reinstall some plugins in this process and may have to retest the app once. But the latest version of Cordova fixes most of the security vulnerabilities for you. We recently got certified our apps in iOS app store that uses Cordova 6.x

Comment: I still don't know how to do that. Please can you help me.

Comment: @KunkumaGeethPrasanna Try running "npm update -g cordova" from command prompt to update your cordova version